# Splitting the row into new line and adding corresponding matching value from other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a datafarme like following

```
  data = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['CTA15;CTA16;CAR;', 'AC007;AC008;GOO7;G008;F009', 'AC09;BC09;C09;V09;B0P', 'UF09;GF09;HF09;MN08'],  
    'Sample':['JAK_1', 'TOR2', 'Gilo', 'ALR']})
data

                Name    Sample
0   CTA15;CTA16;CAR;           JAK_1
1   AC007;AC008;GOO7;G008;F009  TOR2
2   AC09;BC09;C09;V09;B0P       Gilo
3   UF09;GF09;HF09;MN08         ALR
```

And I need to split the column Name and into a new row and add the value in column Sample correspondingly.In the end, I am aiming to have a data frame like this,

```
    Name    Sample
0   CTA15   JAK_1
1   CTA16   JAK_1
2   CAR JAK_1
3   AC007   TOR2
4   AC008   TOR2
5   GOO7    TOR2
6   G008    TOR2
7   F009    TOR2
8   AC09    Gilo
9   BC09    Gilo
10  C09 Gilo
11  V09 Gilo
12  B0P Gilo
13  UF09    ALR
14  GF09    ALR
15  HF09    ALR
16  MN08    ALR
```

I need to split with ';' into the new line and add the value from Sample column to each correspondingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) for remove `;` in start of end of some strings, [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for `list`s, then get [`len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html) for `length` of them.

Last create new `DataFrame` by `constructor` with [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
vals = data['Name'].str.strip(';').str.split(';')
l = vals.str.len()
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sample':np.repeat(data['Sample'].values, l), 
                   'Name':np.concatenate(vals.values)})
print (df)
     Name Sample
0   CTA15  JAK_1
1   CTA16  JAK_1
2     CAR  JAK_1
3   AC007   TOR2
4   AC008   TOR2
5    GOO7   TOR2
6    G008   TOR2
7    F009   TOR2
8    AC09   Gilo
9    BC09   Gilo
10    C09   Gilo
11    V09   Gilo
12    B0P   Gilo
13   UF09    ALR
14   GF09    ALR
15   HF09    ALR
16   MN08    ALR
```

Alternative solution:

```
df = data.join(data.pop('Name')
                   .str.strip(';')
                   .str.split(';', expand=True)
                   .stack()
                   .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
                   .rename('Name')).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   Sample   Name
0   JAK_1  CTA15
1   JAK_1  CTA16
2   JAK_1    CAR
3    TOR2  AC007
4    TOR2  AC008
5    TOR2   GOO7
6    TOR2   G008
7    TOR2   F009
8    Gilo   AC09
9    Gilo   BC09
10   Gilo    C09
11   Gilo    V09
12   Gilo    B0P
13    ALR   UF09
14    ALR   GF09
15    ALR   HF09
16    ALR   MN08
```

Comment: Hello And thank you for the solution, but I am getting the error, as, TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'

Comment: What is your pandas version? `print (pd.show_versions())` ?

Comment: INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 3.4.4.final.0
python-bits: 32
OS: Linux
OS-release: 3.13.0-74-generic
machine: i686
processor: i686
byteorder: little

Comment: It seems like bug, I use `pandas 0.20.2` and it works perfectly.

Comment: Also mine 32 bit